# How To Create History Of Clicked Links In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm needing to create a history trail as a user uses my AngularJS application. Some might think this is a breadcrumb, but not exactly. Nothing needs to be nested. Just a way for them to get back to a certain section of the site without having to use the main navigation. I would think I could build an array of routes that the user clicks on, then display those routes as links in a div as li elements.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
$scope.historyLinks = [];
$scope.addHistory = function(){
    $scope.historyLinks.push(window.location.href);
}
```

And then loop over the $scope.historyLinks array and build an ng-repeat for the recent nav history.

Am I on the right track, or totally off base?

Comment: I would suggest try doing this with an [`interceptor`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: Biased comment here: if you are using `ui-router`, this problem is easily solved by using `ui-router-extras`, where you have `previousState`, which is very similar to your storage of visited routes aka states. Pretty useful for me though. http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky

Comment: unfortunately, the app was built using ngRoute so I don't have the luxury of using ui-router without having to port entire app to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Angular.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $route, $location){
   //Bind the `$locationChangeSuccess` event on the rootScope, so that we dont need to 
   //bind in induvidual controllers.

   var history = [];
   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
         history.push($location.$$path);
    });        

});
```

Note : You can't register from within a controller because $locationChangeSuccess occurs before the route is matched and the controller invoked. By the time you register, the event has already been fired.

However, you can subscribe to the event on $rootScope during the application bootstrap phase: